# msdeploy skip only web.config root

Tags: web-config, root, msdeploy, skip

I'm deploying a website using a package provider with msdeploy and I'm trying to skip only the Web.config root file.

I've got this command but unfortunately it skips any Web.config files not just the root Web.config file that I want. I have read other posts on this forum and different websites about this same issue but it still doesn't work. I don't understand why msdeploy is so complicated to use, it is just ridiculous.

This is the command I'm using:

```
msdeploy -source:package='"src\Parapa.Website\obj\Test\Package\Parapa.Website.csproj.zip"'
-dest:auto,computerName='http://computer/MSDeployAgentService',username='luis',password='luis',includeAcls='False'
-verb:sync 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension
-setParamFile:""src\Parapa.Website\obj\Test\Package\Parapa.Website.csproj.SetParameters.xml"" -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="staging-cm" 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='.*\\Web.config$' 
-enableRule:DoNotDelete

Info: Object filePath (C:\ProgramFiles\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d29656a51131c443\src\Parapa.Website\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config) skipped
Info: Object filePath (C:\ProgramFiles\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d29656a51131c443\src\Parapa.Website\obj\Test\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config) skipped due to skip directive 'CommandLineSkipDirective 1'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the root folder to your Regex expression then it should not skip the web.config in the views folder only the root:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='.*\\PackageTmp\\Web.config$'
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you very much. Could you please explain to me what ".*" means? It keeps confusing me...

Comment: Great. it works to me, in my case i want to  exclude two config files.-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='.*\\PackageTmp\\Web.config$' -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='.*\\PackageTmp\\NLog.config$'

Answer (score 0):

To complement about chief7 mentions about:

`-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='.*\\PackageTmp\\Web.config$'`

this command works if you are using -enableRule:DoNotDelete, because the web.config will be skipped from the source but will be deleted from the target.
So if you are not using the -enableRule:DoNotDelete, another approach is using the skipAction over the target web.config.

`-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='{WebSiteName}\\Web\.config$',skipAction=Update`

replace {WebSiteName} by your web site name.

e.g

`-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath='CommicsTest\\Web\.config$',skipAction=Update`